# Uploading images without ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I am creating a page for adding products to the web shop by the user, and I am having troubles with uploading images.

I have a form with an `<input type="file">` and after selecting the files, the files (images) should be temporarily uploaded to the server. After the upload is complete, image preview should be displayed. During the upload, loading spinner GIF with client-side progress indication should be displayed too, along with the option to cancel the upload. Each uploaded image should have an option to be deleted, once uploaded.

Because of all this and other reasons, I'm not using a ModelForm, but creating everything manually.

So, my plan is to attach an onchange listener to that input, and upon files selection, a POST XMLHttpRequest would be sent from JavaScript, which would call a view that would save the images into some kind of table for temporarily uploaded images, and the ID of the row would be something like `request.session.session_key`, but a little bit different. My issue with this approach is generating that session key, which should be unique and it should last as long as the page is opened. So, refreshing the page would mean generating a new key. `request.session.session_key` doesn't suit my needs as it remains the same throughout the session. When entire form is submitted, I plan to somehow connect those temporarily uploaded images with my main product instance, and delete them from the table for temporary images.

What do you think of this solution, and if it is viable, how to generate the key?

@EDIT:

`models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    free_shipping = models.BooleanField()
    stock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)


class Book(Product):
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Shoes(Product):
    size = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Show your model or the model type that your using for the images

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar done using Angular

`products.ts`

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let me = this;
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function () {
          me.imagen = reader.result;
      };
      reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
      };
    }
}

onSubmit(f){
   // f is my form 
   let postdata=f.value;
   postdata.imagen={'imagen': this.imagen};
   postdata.usuario=+localStorage.getItem("id_usuario");
   postdata.categoria=+postdata.categoria;
   postdata.precio=+postdata.precio;
   postdata.donacion=+postdata.donacion;
   console.log(postdata);
   this.articuloServicio.postNuevoArticulo(postdata)
   .subscribe(res=>{
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/mis_productos')
   },(error=>{
      alert('Error, verifique la informacion ingresada');
   }));
}
```

`models.py`

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes/',blank=False, null=False)
    articule=models.ForeignKey(Articule,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="images", 
    null=False, blank=False)
```

Some images can be for the same product

`serializers.py`

```
class ArticuloSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

imagen = ImagenCreateSerializer(write_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Articulo
    fields = ('id', 'categoria','usuario','nombre','precio','donacion','descrip', 'imagen')

def create(self, validated_data):
    imagenes = validated_data.pop('imagen')
    articulo = Articulo(**validated_data)
    articulo.save()
    for imagen in imagenes.values():
        Imagen.objects.create(articulo=articulo, imagen=imagen)
    return articulo
```

`views.py`

```
class ArticulosList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

queryset = Articulo.objects.all()
serializer_class = ArticuloSerializer
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Articulo.objects.all()
    serializer = ArticuloSerializerDetail(queryset, context={'request': request}, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ArticuloSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In `products.ts`: In onFileChanged, that manage the file upload, I use Filereader to get the image an is assigned to a 
variable in my Angular component. In onSubmit, I get the data from my form f and the image, all the data is located in an object
to be sended in my service in a POST request.

In `models.py` I share my Image model, that is attached to an Articule, that is other model in my schema. The image field is a
`ImageField` from Django.

In `serializers.py` I share my ArticuleSerializer that serialize the data for my Articule get and post views. As you can see
there is a `create` function, in that you can define how the data is managed when is a post request.

In `views.py`, I define my Articule view for get and post, the one for post is the `create` function. To call that view
in your `urls.py` assign it as

```
path("endpoint/", ArticuleList.as_view({"get": "list", "post": "create"}))
```